# SharePoint 2013 Add Custom Refinement "Sort By" option

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search, refinement-panel, refiner

In SP 2013 with refiners you have the ability to Sort By Name, Count, Number. Each of my lists have a Title and Order column. I want the items in my refinement panel on the search page to be sorted by the "Order" column in the list and display the title. Any ideas would be great if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I figured a way to do this.

1. I created a new column called "Order". The order column contained unqiue numeric values in the order to be sorted in.
2. Then I created a new calculated column called "OrderBy" which took the "Order" & ":" & "Title" column.
3. In search schema I associated a refinementstring to this new column.
4. I then created a custom Display template filter.
5. In the custom display template filter (Which I copied from the out of the box one), there is a function called "outputFilter".
6. I took the refinementName parameter value from "outputFilter" function and stripped off the "Number:" prefix from calulcated column. For example the calculated column returned 5:Some Title. My javascript would strip off "5:" so now the refinement would show just "Some Title" in the refinement panel but yet it was sorted by the number.

Comment: That sounds like so much work. Are you certain that you are using numeric values all the way from the Column through to the managed property?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the "Sortable" attribute for your Order Managed Property and then performed a full crawl?

Comment: Yes, the OOTB one I am using RefinableString01. The refinement panel is using that. But my problem is I need it to be sorted by column A but show column B in the refinement panel. I cant see how that is possible.

Comment: I think you would have to write the refiner (Display Templates\Filter) your self to achieve this. Unless you apply the sort order to the Search Core Results. I have not tried that.

Comment: I was able to acheive this by using custom JS code.

Comment: Can you share the solution you found?

Comment: See my answer below.